# The drawbacks of Short time fourier transform

Tags: fft, time-frequency

I have read the following sentence in a documents talk about the drawback of short time Fourier transform, and  he is said :

> the drawback is that once you choose a particular size for the time
>   window, that window is the same for all frequencies

So what is the relation between frequencies and the size of window. If we have a high frequency component in a part of a signal how will not be able to detect this frequency if the size of the window is not smaller/bigger enough?

Furthermore, he is said about wavelet transform :

> Wavelet analysis allows the use of long time intervals where we want
>   more precise low-frequency information, and shorter regions where we
>   want high-frequency information

I feel that the answer has a relation with nyquest rate somehow

Answer (score 1):

For sampled data, the number of orthogonal sinusoidal FT basis vectors below half the sample rate increases with the length of the STFT window, and the bandwidth of each DFT/FFT result bin for each basis vector decreases.  If the window is too short, then each DFT result might detect not only your high frequency component of interest, but a greater bandwidth of adjacent frequencies.